# Should I create new smaller array from decoded JSON or use the whole JSON array as is?

Tags: php, arrays, json

My API call returns a pretty big JSON result and my initial thought was to parse out the two pieces of data I need for each event and create my own array. Does it make more sense to pass around the returned JSON or clean it up for my use throughout the application. 
Which is more efficient?

Below is an example of one "Event" each result may have 20-50 events in the data. All I need is the `['resultsPage']['results']['event']['location']['lng']` and `['resultsPage']['results']['event']['location']['lat']`:

```
{
  "resultsPage": {
    "results": {
      "event": [
        {
          "id":11129128,
          "type":"Concert",
          "uri":"http://www.songkick.com/concerts/11129128-wild-flag-at-fillmore?utm_source=PARTNER_ID&utm_medium=partner",
          "displayName":"Wild Flag at The Fillmore (April 18, 2012)",
          "start": {
            "time":"20:00:00",
            "date":"2012-04-18",
            "datetime":"2012-04-18T20:00:00-0800"
          },
          "performance": [
            {
              "artist": {
                "id":29835,
                "uri":"http://www.songkick.com/artists/29835-wild-flag?utm_source=PARTNER_ID&utm_medium=partner",
                "displayName":"Wild Flag",
                "identifier": []
              },
              "id":21579303,
              "displayName":"Wild Flag",
              "billingIndex":1,
              "billing":"headline"
            }
          ],
          "location": {
            "city":"San Francisco, CA, US",
            "lng":-122.4332937,
            "lat":37.7842398
          },
          "venue": {
            "id":6239,
            "displayName":"The Fillmore",
            "uri":"http://www.songkick.com/venues/6239-fillmore?utm_source=PARTNER_ID&utm_medium=partner",
            "lng":-122.4332937,
            "lat":37.7842398,
            "metroArea": {
              "id":26330,
              "uri":"http://www.songkick.com/metro_areas/26330-us-sf-bay-area?utm_source=PARTNER_ID&utm_medium=partner",
              "displayName":"SF Bay Area",
              "country": { "displayName":"US" },
              "state": { "displayName":"CA" }
            }
          },
          "status":"ok",
          "popularity":0.012763
        }, ....
      ]
    },
    "totalEntries":24,
    "perPage":50,
    "page":1,
    "status":"ok"
  }
}
```

Comment: just output what you really need, who uses the server response? maybe using paging? maybe ask yourself, do you really need tons of data? or maybe you can feed like 50 or 100 at a time, not the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

My subjective answer is to just use the entire response in your application, grabbing only what you need when you need it. Taking the time to extract only the data you need might be an unnecessary optimization, and your time could be better spent elsewhere.

Optimize only what you measure. If you can measure your application execution time, perhaps with the help of a profiler, like [this one with Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler), then you can use data to make an informed decision to optimize in this way. My guess is that your application could use optimizations elsewhere before you make this one, but again, without data, it's just a guess.

Comment: Thank you. You have given me a great starting point and a lot to research. Thanks for taking the time to give me your opinion.